# Is there any command that prints library info? (C++)

Tags: c++

Is there any command (in C++) that prints which libraries are available or/and info about how to use a specific library?

I am asking this question because, in a programming language like Python, help() is a useful function (when internet connection is not available for example):

```
>>> import random
>>> help(random)
"Help on module random: (...)"
```

Comment: No such thing built into the standard C++ language or library.

Comment: Dynamic languages such as Python usually have a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) because statements can be executed independently. This does not exist natively for C++ due to its static nature. The only way to know what libraries/include files are available is to look on disk for the directories where they are stored (eg. /usr/include, /usr/lib ... ).

Comment: Many C library functions have man pages...

Comment: You could spend a long time writing your own function, that parses header files, and reads the documentation. There are better solutions. Many IDEs can take you right to the function/type in the header file with a shortcut click, like `cmd` + `rmb` in Xcode. `stdlib` doesn't have a documentation in the provided header files by Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, there is no `help` function per se in the C++ language or library.

**Long answer:** Your intention is probably to learn about some function from the library that you want to use now in your C++ program.

If that is your intention, (viz-e-vie [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), then indeed there are solutions.

- On *Linux*, read (POSIX), we have the wonderful [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++). You can basically lookup any function there, with all its parameters, return types and sometimes even examples.
- On Windows, we have the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/?view=vs-2017) (Correct me if I am wrong, someone. I don't work in that world.)
- Personally, if I want to see how to use a function, its parameters, return type, etc. whether I am using *Qt-Creator* or *Eclipse*, I just hover over the function name and let *intellisense* do its job. I expect the same to be possible in *Visual Studio* as well.
- Press `CTRL` and click on the function name and mostly you can even jump into the header file and get more intuition about how best to use that particular function.